# Trying to change url ending in Python

Tags: python

I am having a problem with adding random letters and numbers to the ending of a URL.

I have tried `webbrowser.open("www.mylinkabc1234/", randomString)` but it does not seem like it's working. It will just bring me to the website as if I had not even added the characters and numbers onto the URL.

```
def randomString(stringLength=2):
    """Generate a random string of fixed length """
    letters = string.ascii_lowercase
    return ''.join(random.choice(letters) for i in range(stringLength))

webbrowser.open("www.blah.com/{0}", randomString)
```

I'm trying to make a random image finder on a certain website with the use of the random numbers and letter that it requires. This is a project for school, so any timely responses are greatly appreciated.

Comment: Try `webbrowser.open("www.blah.com/{0}".format(randomString()))`

Comment: @Nikscorp I am getting a syntax error if I do that.

Answer (score 0):

The working code example:

```py
import string
import webbrowser
import random

def randomString(stringLength=2):
    """Generate a random string of fixed length"""
    letters = string.ascii_lowercase
    return ''.join(random.choice(letters) for i in range(stringLength))

webbrowser.open("www.blah.com/{0}".format(randomString()))
```

Looking at your examples, i guess you don't know any of python basics (what is a function, how to call it, etc.). You should first take some python course or read the documentation or book and then try to implement your idea, otherwise your productivity will be very low and the code will be a mess.